# Google Script does not trigger as expected given row conditions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the 2 columns in my table schema:

Column D= Date, i.e. 20180611 [yyymmdd]
Column F= Continuous Value, i.e. 0.1, 0.6, -0.3 etc.

**This is what I want to happen:**

Check in column D for yesterday's date. Then, take in the corresponding row, and check if column F is greater than 0.5 (for yesterday's date). If TRUE, then send an email alert.

This is the script I have but it does not trigger for some reason. What is wrong with it?

```
function readCell() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
    var dates = sheet.getRange('D1:D').getValues();

    var date = null;
    var dateRow = 0;
    var dateCount = dates.length;
    var yesterday = new Date(); 
    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1); 
    var yesterdayString = yesterday.toDateString();

    for (dateRow; dateRow < dateCount; ++dateCount) {

        try {

            date = dates[dateRow].toDateString();

            if (date === yesterdayString) {
                ++dateRow;
                // To account for zero-based array
                break;
            }

        } catch (error) {
            Logger.log(error);
        }
    }

    var value = sheet.getRange('F' + dateRow).getValue();

    if (value >= 0.5) {
      var result = ('Alert found on: ' + date);
      MailApp.sendEmail('blabla@gmail.com', 'Alert', result);
    }
};
```

Here is the data
[image]

Comment: Functions don't just run by themselves. Did you manually execute this function? Did you create an installed trigger for it? Did you do **any** debugging at all, to look at the values certain variables have while it is executing?

Comment: Well, i clicked in "Run function" in the menu. When I run the function, it takes forever and at some point it stops executing. I added a screenshot to show the data. I only have 219 rows so far in time. Does it take the fct so long due to the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be due to the use of an open reference `D2:D` to get values and then use `dates.length` to set the number of iterations on the for loop because it could be a number too large.

One "quick and dirty" way that could solve the above issue is to replace

```
var dateCount = dates.length;
```

by

```
var dateCount = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length;
```